# Join six five-link chains to form a circular chain

Tags: geometry, topology

> Join six five-link chains to form a circular chain.
>   To join two chains, you must cut, and then re-weld, a link.

The final number of links in the circular chain will be 30.

What is the minimum number of links you must cut and re-weld 
to complete the circle/chain?

Comment: Think of each of the five-link chains as a line of hoops or rings that are connected end to end.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this before... (Also, [tag:logic-puzzle] should only be used for puzzles about logical deduction.)

Comment: (Not entirely sure if [tag:topology] applies here.)

Comment: @Deusovi Topology seems like a ... not-unreasonable tag to me?

Comment: @question_asker Yeah, it's clearly relevant, but I don't know if it's relevant *enough* or just part of the puzzle "dressing" - it could probably go either way.

Comment: The final number of links in the circle is not specified, leading me to my answer.

Comment: @OliveStemforn Click the green checkmark beside the answer that you said solved it correctly.

Comment: @goodguy5 - I didn't think I should have to specify it, but I did so.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave my answer up and comment that the question was edited. Cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 5 Links.  Cut one of the segments into separate links,(5 cuts) and use them between each of the 5 remaining segments to form a circle (5 welds)

Answer (score 5):

> Edit: The question was changed to stipulate that the chain should become a circle of 30 links in length. While this "solution" is a circle with 30 links, it is only 10 links long and is no longer valid after the update.

As is usual with these puzzles, I'm not sure if this is allowed:

> Cut both ends of the first chain 
> Line up one side of the links of the other 5 chains 
>  Weld the broken link through all 5 whole links. 
>  repeat for the other side 
>  You should now have a "circle" of 10 links around, that has a fat one side (5 chains thick!) 
>  This means that the answer is **2** cuts. See Images.

Just leave a comment if you need clarification.

> [image: Step one] [image: Step two]

Comment: In that case you can do it with _one_ cut. Cut one link in one chain, gather up the other links of that chain in the cut link, and then also gather up the two end links from all the other chains. You'll have a circular chain that's five chains wide, with a funny fat link connecting the two ends.

Comment: I thought about that, but then you'd have a "tail" on the end. While useful for beating your opponents, somewhat contrary to a circle.