# Join neckles to make one

Tags: mathematics

> Join five three-link chains to one 15-link chain
> To join two chains, you must cut, and then re-weld, a link.
> The new chain should have exactly two ends (no more, no less).

The questions is what is the minum re-weld and link steps that are required to make the new desired chain.

Visually the question can be shown as the figure below[image]

The answer that I would give is the following:

> The answer that I think is correct is 4. The steps - re-weld first three-link chain and link it to the second. Then re-weld second three-link chain and link it to the third one, etc, etc to the last one. This makes 4 re-welds and links.

Am I missing something because this looks like a simple question

Comment: 3 is possible....

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/join-six-five-link-chains-to-form-a-circular-chain is essentially the same puzzle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join six five-link chains to form a circular chain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/join-six-five-link-chains-to-form-a-circular-chain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three.........................

> [image]